# Unable to receive/preview funds due to un-synced wallet

Tags: transactions, wallet, exchanges, synchronization, payment

I bought bitcoins and sent them to the wallet, however the wallet is not synchronized and as a result I cannot see my bitcoins.

Will I be able to see them as soon as the synchronization process finishes or have I lost them?

If I did, is there any way I can recover them?

Answer (score 2):

You will be able to see them as soon as you synch the block that contains the payment.